# TP-Link MR3020 doesn`t start wifi after openWRT firmware

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, dd-wrt

I wanted to download OpenWRT on my tp-link MR3020, so I downloaded this file [openwrt-15.05.1-ar71xx-generic-tl-mr3020-v1-squashfs-factory.bin](https://downloads.openwrt.org/chaos_calmer/15.05.1/ar71xx/generic/openwrt-15.05.1-ar71xx-generic-tl-mr3020-v1-squashfs-factory.bin) but it did not accept it so I changed its name to [openwrt-15.05.1-ar71xx-generic-tl-mr3020-v1-squashfs-sysupgrade.bin](https://downloads.openwrt.org/chaos_calmer/15.05.1/ar71xx/generic/openwrt-15.05.1-ar71xx-generic-tl-mr3020-v1-squashfs-sysupgrade.bin)

and it worked but it took forever to reboot about(2 hrs) So i Thought that something is wrong so I disconnected it form the power source now when connect it to a power source only the power light turns on I tried pressing the reset button following instructions on openWrt Fail safe but nothing worked

,thank you
I am kind of new to this so if I made a stupid Mistake or did something Stupid I am sorry

Comment: Let me see what I can find for your router. It sounds like something went wrong in the flash process.

Comment: What's the revision number of your router?

Comment: NVM I didn`t read the [firstlogin](https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/firstlogin) guide,sorry

Comment: If you don't mind, you can answer questions you asked yourself. It may help someone else in the same situation.

Comment: I don`t know the answer I just followed the instructions in [firstlogin](https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/firstlogin)

Comment: lol then that is the answer if it worked for you